# Типы итераторов стандартных шаблонов

Tags: c++, классы, stl, шаблоны-с++

Предположим, есть некоторый шаблонный класс, использующий контейнер из библиотеки STL:

```
#include <array>

template <typename T, size_t D>
class default_name
{
  std::array<Type, Dim> container;
  ...    
}
```

Я хочу переопределить `begin()` , `end()` и прочие функции, связанные с итераторами, для своего класса так, чтобы они использовали итераторы внутреннего контейнера и соответственно, его функции `begin()` , `end()` и другие.

В этом случае мне нужно указать возвращаемое значение функций-членов моего класса.

Собственно, вопрос, как получить или сослаться на тип итераторов внутреннего контейнера?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <array>

template <typename T, size_t D>
class default_name{
    typedef std::array<T, D> Container;
    Container container;
public:
    typedef typename Container::iterator Iterator;
    typedef typename Container::const_iterator ConstIterator;

    Iterator begin(){
        return container.begin();
    }
    Iterator end(){
        return container.begin();
    }

    ConstIterator begin() const{
        return container.begin();
    }
    ConstIterator end() const{
        return container.begin();
    }
};
```

Comment: Вопрос связанный, но чуть дальше от темы. В каких случаях вызовется функция const итератора?

Comment: @Gordory, если честно, я не понял что значит *"функция const итератора"*. Если вы имели ввиду константные методы `begin` и `end`, то они вызываются у константных объектов, ссылок и указателей. `const default_name *ptr; ptr->begin(); //ConstIterator begin() const`

Comment: Криво сформулировал. Да, именно, спасибо.